# sftp, scp to GoDaddy server Permission denied

Tags: file-sharing, scp

I am trying to sftp or scp from the command line on my Pi to my GoDaddy server. I'm able to connect to the server with CyberDuck on my Mac and on a windows machine but I can't get my Pi to connect from the command line.

I did go into the Pi configuration and enable SSH.

```
sftp wcwc@blah.com
```

```
scp /home/pi/Pictures/image.jpg wcwc@blah.com:/
```

I'm prompted for a password, then access denied in both cases.

I looked in the log files but didn't see any errors coming back from the server, but I may not have looked in the right log?

I'm out of ideas.

UPDATE

Thank you for your response. The -vvv is huge.

Do I have to install some kind of ssh key and have a password?

In the debug script I see:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: password
wcwc@cliffandbuster.com's password:
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
Permission denied, please try again.
wcwc@blah.com's password:
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
Permission denied, please try again.
wcwc@blah.com's password:
```

Same results.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the last sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site I'm trying to sftp to is a subdomain under a master domain. Long story short you can't sftp to a subdomain with this hosting provider. I can old school ftp but there is a trust issue I have to work through.

Ingo, thanks for your help. The -vvv was a huge tip.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 2):

With

```
rpi ~$ scp /home/pi/Pictures/image.jpg wcwc@blah.com:/
```

you are trying to copy the image to the root directory `/` on `blah.com`. Doing such things isn't allowed usually for normal user. You get the error message

```
scp: /image.jpg: Permission denied
```

Verify `scp` with copying to the default home directory of the user with

```
rpi ~$ scp /home/pi/Pictures/image.jpg wcwc@blah.com:.
```

Note the dot as last character.

If you can use `ssh wcwc@blah.com` then you should also be able to use `sftp wcwc@blah.com`. It is just using ssh but only with another user interface. Check with the verbose option `-vvv` what's the problem:

```
sftp -vvv wcwc@blah.com
```

If you are asked for a password, just enter the password of **wcwc** that is used to login on server `blah.com` if you are sitting in front of it.